# How to add days to a date in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, update

I have two tables and I want to execute an update similar to this:

```
UPDATE table1 set table1.date = table2.date + table2.numberOfDays
FROM tabel2
WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

Edit: table1.date and table2.date is a date and table2.numberOfDays is a integer

Comment: Where is the problem (except that you have to write `date` instead of `table1.date`)?

Comment: `set table1.date = table2.date + make_interval(days => table2.numberOfDays)`?

Comment: I edited the question by adding the types

Comment: That should work just fine (if you use `set date = ...` as Laurenz already mentioned). What exactly is the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution

```
UPDATE table1 set table1.date = (table2.date + (table2.numberOfDays || 'day')::INTERVAL)
FROM tabel2
WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id
```

OR

```
UPDATE table1 set table1.date = table2.date + make_interval(days => table2.numberOfDays)
FROM tabel2
WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id
```